# Performing a search on first and last name columns with a single search string that has more than 2 words

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have a query which currently takes a single user supplied search string and tries to search against a table which contains a separate column for firstName and lastName. If the search string has a space in it, the query it runs is essentially like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE table.firstName LIKE @firstName + '%'
AND table.lastName LIKE @lastName + '%'
```

We don't need to concern ourselves with the case of there being no spaces in the search string.

The general case is pretty simple - split the search string on a space, the first part is the first name, the second part is the last name. So, "Bob Smith" becomes

```
@firstName = "Bob", @lastName = "Smith"
```

What I'm hung up on is how to handle cases where the name is more than two words. Situations like

```
table.firstName        table.lastName
---------------        --------------
Bob                    van Smith
Billy Bob              Smith
Bob                    van der Smith  
Billy Bob              van der Smith
```

And so on. Right now we split on the first space, so the first example, "Bob van Smith" will work because it breaks into

```
@firstName: "Bob", @lastName: "van Smith"
```

But, this does not catch the second case "Billy Bob Smith" since it splits into

```
@firstName: "Billy", @lastName: "Bob Smith"
```

The current set up will also work on the third test case, since it splits into

```
@firstName: "Bob", @lastName: "van der Smith"
```

The last case would be bonus points if there was a way to make it work.

My first idea was to just to modify the query to

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE table.firstName + ' ' +  table.lastName LIKE '%' + @searchString + '%'
```

But that was shot down because we don't want someone searching on just the letter 'a' for example to return tons of records, which the double wildcard would create.

Are there any tricks to doing this kind of string split/search? This can't be the first time this has been a problem but searching the internet I haven't been able to find anything except "split on space, but note that it won't work if there are 3 or more words in the name."

I feel like something along the lines of including the "between names" as part of both @firstName and @lastName and doing something clever, or making the SQL part more generic and then doing extra filtering with LINQ in my C# code, but a solution is eluding me.

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem. Take for instance a name like Maria de los Angeles Gomez de la Cruz. I think your design has put you in a box from which there is no easy escape. A robust name matching algorithm has to account for the possibility of people treating the same name differently and allow for name words being missing, crossing first/last boundaries, being misspelled, etc. That is too broad for a simple SO answer.

Comment: @hatchet Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. I've inherited this design and have resistance to making fundamental changes to it, so I figured it wouldn't hurt to see if there was a trick I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by:

1. Using a wildcard to bookend each space separated name against both columns (I could not control name order or require first and last name).
2. I then assign a score based on each match (i.e. was it a whole word match and were there matches in both the first and last name columns)
3. I also had a minimum number of letters to search (min 2 letters)

This worked well for me. You can still generate a large number of matches for small words. The ranking of matches will push poor partial matches to the bottom of the list.

Comment: I like this idea and I think it could be helpful for someone else who might find this question in the future. Unfortunately in my case, the requirement is "match" or "no match." I suspected I had too many constraints for this to really be doable and it seems like I was right

Comment: Where you say match or no match - do you mean on the whole name? If so, just `concat` your `Firstname`/`Lastname` columns first and search on that (i.e. Bob Smith does not match Bob van Smith, you are golden). If you mean not matching partial word matches but flexibility in matching no all the names you can do that as well by splitting up your search words and the words in your `FirstName` / `LastName` columns and evaluating them in order.

Comment: We ended up going with a pretty complex idea of maintaining first and last name search when there is a single space, but concatenating and doing a straight compare, like you suggested here, if there are multiple spaces. Our situation was pretty unique though, I think your answer is better for generic purposes, so I'm marking it accepted

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sql server 2012+ you can use [**CONCAT (Transact-SQL)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx).

```
select *  from [table] where CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) like '%Bob Smith%'
```

In this case you don't need to split anything, just CONCAT your FirstName and LastName and compare it with your input. If you are going always to receive the full name from the input you can even go:

```
select *  from [table] where CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) ='Bob Smith'
```

Of course you will go with **sql parameters** I write it as plain text only to be clear to use the full name input.

Comment: Will this result in table scans for every query?

Comment: @hatchet probably I don't know how he setup his table, there is profiler for such checks.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the idea I had that was shot down?

Comment: @Adam I didn't understand you. For sure this will be faster to be done than searching in 2 columns  with like.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for an exact match to what the user entered, try this:

```
select * 
from table
where @searchString like table.firstName + '%' and @searchString like '%' + table.lastName
and len(table.firstName + ' ' + table.lastName) = len(@searchString)
```